# QGIS does not load Processing algorithm's (raster) output

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, qgis-processing

I wrote a simple QGIS Processing algorithm:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.processing import alg
import processing


@alg(name="test", label=alg.tr("test"), group="test", group_label=alg.tr("test"))
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], name="POINTS_INPUT", label="Point layer")
@alg.input(type=alg.RASTER_LAYER_DEST, name="OUTPUT", label="Raster output layer")
def test(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """Description goes here. (Don't delete this! Removing this comment will cause errors.)"""

    buffer = processing.run(
        "native:buffer",
        {
            "INPUT": parameters["POINTS_INPUT"],
            "DISTANCE": 100,
            "OUTPUT": "memory:",
        },
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context,
        feedback=feedback,
    )
    
    rasterize = processing.run(
        "gdal:rasterize",
        {
            'INPUT': buffer["OUTPUT"],
            'BURN': 123,
            'UNITS': 1,
            'WIDTH': 10,
            'HEIGHT': 10,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
        },
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context,
        feedback=feedback,
    )

    return {"OUTPUT": rasterize["OUTPUT"]}
```

When I run it from the GUI and have the appropriate checkbox to load its result after success, QGIS does *not* load it. There is a valid TIF file created in my temporary Processing directory. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're specifying a RASTER_LAYER_DEST as the OUTPUT parameter but not passing it to `processing.run("gdal:rasterize")`.

The return value of the algorithm is used for passing results to other algorithms, e. g. in the modeller.

This version works and adds the output to the map.

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.processing import alg
import processing


@alg(name="test", label=alg.tr("test"), group="test", group_label=alg.tr("test"))
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], name="POINTS_INPUT", label="Point layer")
@alg.input(type=alg.RASTER_LAYER_DEST, name="OUTPUT", label="Raster output layer")
def test(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """Description goes here. (Don't delete this! Removing this comment will cause errors.)"""

    buffer = processing.run(
        "native:buffer",
        {
            "INPUT": parameters["POINTS_INPUT"],
            "DISTANCE": 100,
            "OUTPUT": "memory:",
        },
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context,
        feedback=feedback,
    )
    
    rasterize = processing.run(
        "gdal:rasterize",
        {
            'INPUT': buffer["OUTPUT"],
            'BURN': 123,
            'UNITS': 1,
            'WIDTH': 10,
            'HEIGHT': 10,
            'OUTPUT': parameters["OUTPUT"],  # pass RASTER_LAYER_DEST instead of TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        },
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context,
        feedback=feedback,
    )

    return {"OUTPUT": rasterize["OUTPUT"]}
```